# When is the stack of Error objects generated?

Tags: javascript, v8

Every time I instantiate an Error object there is a `.stack` field. Assuming that building a stacktrace is a costly operation, my natural reaction is to reserve their use for exceptional cases.

However I remember reading that in v8 the stacktrace is only calculated upon read of the `.stack` field.

Can I assume that `new Error(...)` is just as expensive as `new Object(...)` if I never read the stack ?

Is this a feature of the JS engine or a standard behavior?

Comment: Can't you just log the error?

Comment: Collecting the stack trace is still a costly operation, even if it's not formatted and stored as a string yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Error.prototype.stack`](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-TW/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/Stack) is a non-standard feature, so its behavior depends on the implementation.

In the case of platforms based on V8, the [wiki](https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Stack-Trace-API) on the GitHub says:

> The stack trace is collected when the error is created and is the same
>   regardless of where or how many times the error is thrown.

And the [document](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_class_error) of Node.js also says the same thing:

> Error objects capture a "stack trace" detailing the point in the code
>   at which the Error was instantiated, and may provide a text
>   description of the error.

So it is already **collected** when the `Error` object is created.

However, it is not **formatted** until the first time the `stack` property is accessed, as the paragraph on the same wiki page states:

> For efficiency stack traces are not formatted when they are captured
>   but on demand, the first time the stack property is accessed.